# PHP SHA1 function in Java

Tags: java, php, android, hash

I was wondering if there is any way to get the PHP SHA1 with raw returning in Java. Just like this in PHP: sha1("abc123", true) Anyone got an idea? It would be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like

```
java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest("abc123".getBytes())
```

(maybe you want to pass the Charset to getBytes()) or use [org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils#sha1(String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha1%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks very much! My app now works!